# How can I set a password of a user doc for a Meteor app running on Modulus?

Tags: meteor, modulus

I have a Meteor app running on Modulus and I need to *set* (not *reset*) a user's password.
There is the [Accounts.setPassword()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_setpassword) method, but it can only be executed from server code.

However, I'm not aware of something like [meteor shell](http://info.meteor.com/blog/meteor-102-meteor-shell) for Modulus.

How can I run server code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [source code of Meteor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js) tells us how exactly passwords are hashed:

```
// Use bcrypt to hash the password for storage in the database.
// `password` can be a string (in which case it will be run through
// SHA256 before bcrypt) or an object with properties `digest` and
// `algorithm` (in which case we bcrypt `password.digest`).
//
var hashPassword = function (password) {
  password = getPasswordString(password);
  return bcryptHash(password, Accounts._bcryptRounds);
};
```

And also:

```
Accounts._bcryptRounds = 10;
```

Thus you can simply create a new hash by first applying SHA256 and then a 10-round bcrypt on the raw password string.

If you only have one or two passwords to modify, and wish to update them by hand, here are some online tools to do that:

[Online SHA-256 calculator](http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator)

[Online bcrypt calculator](https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator)

After you created a new hash, just update it using the Mongo console:

```
db.users.update({"emails.address": "my@email.com"}, {$set: {"services.password.bcrypt": "$2a$10$u/4JV2MrAKb8Jk9yRHDIL.yGn5SQOInFunvUwEnDv5uJgMkWNe08K"}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a [Meteor method](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods) which does what I need.

However I don't really like the idea of it and think there should be a better way.